# Allow to enter percentage values between 1...100 with lightning:input

Tags: lightning, lightning-design-system, slds

I am unable to configure a `lightning:input` to allow a user to **input 50 when he wants 50%**. It always does strange conversions.

Please provide me with a

```
<lightning:input type="number" formatter="percent"... />
```

that fulfills this specification:

1. Allow numbers from 0 to 100
2. Maximum 1 decimal point
3. Minimal width of the field (as small as possible)

Comment: Try using formattednumber if you are facing issues with lightning:input, you can set minimum values using this component https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_formattedNumber.htm

Comment: I need an INPUT field, not an OUTPUT field.

Comment: 1 : Input validation ; 2 : Input validation ; 3 : CSS. Input validation documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_validate_fields.htm ; CSS : https://www.w3schools.com/css/ ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one? Doesn't match the spec but looks most percent-ish

```
<div class="slds-form slds-form_inline">
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <lightning:input name="foo" label="foo" type="number" min="0" max="1" formatter="percent" step="0.01"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

You edit the values as "0,04" but when you leave the field they display as "4%".

Alternatively admit defeat, go with `<lightning:input name="bar" label="bar" type="number" min="0" max="100"/>` and divide by 100 in controller...

Comment: What I simply don't get is why Lightning input fields change the semantics Salesforce users learned for a century ( and which is way more intuitive ) namely enterin 50 when I want to have 50 %. This still works this way in native UI fields.