# Clickable Icon in Input field using Lightning Base Components

Tags: lightning-design-system

How can I implement this [input field with a right icon button from the LSDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input/) using Lightning Base Components?

[image]

This doesn't work

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
   <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right">
      <lightning:input type="number" name="percentVal" formatter="percent" step="0.01" />
      <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:rules" variant="bare" />
   </div>
</div>
```

The icon gets displayed below the input field

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the appropriate classes to the button icon:

```
class="slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right"
```

..

```
<div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right">
    <lightning:buttonIcon size="medium" iconName="utility:close" class="front slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right" variant="bare"/>
    <lightning:input type="number" name="percentVal"  formatter="percent" step="0.01" />

</div>
```

[image]

In my case I had to add css to make the z-index 1. You may not have to but in the page I was testing on it was needed

```
.THIS .front{
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: The icon is not centered correctly..

Comment: @RobertSösemann - Not sure how you want it but open up the dom inspector and start adding classes tot he icon to get it like you want it. Then add those classes / css to the icon in your component....maybe a `slds-p-top_small` or something. It is a PITA though as none of this "just works" lol

Comment: Works! But how do I get the input field to leave 50 untouched as 50% and not converting it to 0.5?

Comment: @RobertSösemann - That my friend is a whole mother issue. I think I saw a similar question today - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193168/allow-to-enter-percentage-values-between-1-100-with-lightninginput

Comment: Yeah, it was mine ;-) I like "whole mother" :-D

Comment: Was supposed to be "whole nother" issue. I'll leave it for ya though since both are grammatically incorrect anyway lol